# How to know when dataimporthandler for solr finished indexing?

Tags: indexing, solr, apache-zookeeper, solrcloud

Is it possibile to know where solr finished to index my data?

I work with solrcloud 4.9.0 and zookeeper for conf file manager.
I have the data.import file, but in it there is only where the indexing is STARTED not when it ended.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can get the dataimporthandler status using:

```
<MY_SERVER>/solr/dataimport?command=status
```

Reading the status you can understand if the import is still running. A similar procedure (with a different url) is advised in "Solr in Action" book in order to check if a backup is still running. 
Another option would involve the use of listeners as advised [here](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/DataImportHandler#EventListeners).

Comment: if the status is 'idle', you can conclude that the indexing is completed.

Answer (score 1):

I also use the /dataimport?command=status way to check if the job is done or not, and while it works, sometimes I get the impression it is a bit flaky.

There are listeners you can use: [see here](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DataImportHandler#EventListeners) I would really like to use those, but of course you need to write java code and handle your jar in solr etc. So it is a bit of a PITA

Comment: tank you very much!

Comment: I don't have issues using this method in standalone mode, but once I moved to using SolrCloud I found that `command=status` is unreliable, as you mentioned.